# Conditionally draw connecting lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot wind direction measurements on a cartesian plot with time on the X axis and direction on the Y axis. Because direction wraps when moving from 359 to 0 degrees, it is inappropriate to draw a line connecting 359 to 0.

Is it possible to conditinally draw connecting lines if the shorter jump does not wrap? i.e. Here is a sequence of values with connecting lines where appropriate:

10—15—30—90—150—290—350 40—50—20 310—250—150

I assume I would use something like the following formula to determine if there should be a line between A and B:

```
max(A,B) - min(A,B) <= 180
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question, I came up with a working approach: Simply adding a `None` value indicates that the data are not continuous and the line is broken.

To make it perfect, I added points outside my range so that lines will eg leave the plot at the top and come out of the bottom.

This was done with a simple generator that adds the relevant data points:

```py
def break_degree_wrap(values):
    values1, values2 = itertools.tee(values)

    # Yield the first value
    yield next(values2)

    for (prev_datetime, prev_val), (datetime, val) in itertools.izip(values1, values2):

        # If the data wraps over the top
        if val > prev_val and val - prev_val > 180:
            yield (datetime, val - 360)
            yield (datetime, None)
            yield (prev_datetime, prev_val + 360)

        # If the data wraps under the bottom
        elif val < prev_val and prev_val - val > 180:
            yield (datetime, val + 360)
            yield (datetime, None)
            yield (prev_datetime, prev_val - 360)

        # Add each original value
        yield (datetime, val)
```

This could be easily generalised to accept a valid range, instead of the hardcoded (0, 360).

Here is how it looks (excuse the poor axes :-)
[image: Wind direction]

Answer (score 3):

I always use the np.diff() function to get the point where a change is larger then 180 degrees and insert a masked element. The main downside is that you also have to keep an 'index' for plotting.

So:

```
a = np.array([10,15,30,90,150,290,350,40,50,20,310,250,150])
idx = np.arange(len(a))

b = np.diff(a)
mask = np.where(np.abs(b) >= 180)[0]+1

c = np.ma.masked_equal(np.insert(a, mask, -1), -1)
idx = np.ma.masked_equal(np.insert(idx, mask, -1), -1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))

ax.plot(idx, c)
ax.set_xticks(idx)
ax.set_ylim(0,360)
```

[image]

This does not insert a value outside of the range, but i guess that could be added. Instead of 1 masked element you could insert 2 elements going 'out' and 'in' the graph again.

Also note that the threshold of 180 degrees is just an assumption, you don't really know whether the wind is backing or veering unless you actually measure it.

Comment: Good point with the 180 degrees, but it should be ok: we are working with averages and the line is actually a trend, as opposed to the actual movement.